# Private members in module pattern, not mutable?

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function modify(val, newVal) {
    val = newVal;
}
constructorFunc = function () {
    var _private = false;

    return {
        modifyPrivate: function(toVal) {
            return modify(_private, toVal);  // LINE REFERRED TO BELOW AS X
        }
    };
}
var x = constructorFunc(); 
x.modifyPrivate(true); 
x.modifyPrivate(true);  // _private still starts off as false, meaning it wasn't set to true
```

The one question I have is why the second time I call x.modifyPrivate(true) why is it that when line X is run, the value of _private passed in is still 'false'.

I can make sense of this if I modify my knowledge of closures slightly to be that the closure is done by reference, and when you change the value of a reference you are not chaning the value the original reference pointed to, you are changing the reference itself to point to some new value... But this whole thing is very confusing and I'm sure someone out there can point me to a diagram on the net that explains this.

I'm also very interested in knowing how to write this code so that _private is in fact modified for the subsequent calls to modify().

Comment: Arguments are passed by value in JS. That means your `modify` function is efficiently meaningless. Even if `val` there referred to an object, the value of its _local_ copy (= reference as well) would be rewritten - not the object itself.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I can't believe I forgot that.  Closures use reference, function calls use value.  Right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript always passes by value, so there's no way to pass a variable to a function and have the function assign a new value to it as you tried to do.

The `modify` function is actually not needed at all. Just do this:

```
constructorFunc = function () {
    var _private = false;

    return {
        modifyPrivate: function(toVal) {
            _private = toVal;
            return this; 
        }
    };
}
var x = constructorFunc(); 
x.modifyPrivate(true);
```

The method `modifyPrivate` has access to the private `_private`, since it was defined in an inner scope. It's returning `this` as suggested by raina77ow, so you can chain another method call of `x` if you wish (e.g. `x.modifyPrivate(true).foo()`, if you define `foo` like you did for `modifyPrivate`).

---

Now, if you really need to modify the value from an external function that doesn't have access to that scope, you can wrap you private value in an object, and pass the object. In this case, the passed value will be a reference to the object, so modifying its properties would work (note that you can't reassign to the object, just manipulate the properties):

```
function modify(valObj, newVal) {
    valObj.val = newVal;
    // return whatever is apropriate
}
constructorFunc = function () {
    var _private = {
        val : false
    };

    return {
        modifyPrivate: function(toVal) {
            return modify(_private, toVal);
        }
    };
}
var x = constructorFunc(); 
x.modifyPrivate(true);
```

Comment: I'd prefer returning `this` in setters. )

Comment: Makes sense; returning `toVal` was a guess, I'm not sure what the OP wants to return (original code returned `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks, I get you.  In reality the modify function is a "set or get" depending on whether or not there was a value, and if the value is changed it updates my database, and it also caches values so it doesn't always fetch from database.  I will need to ask this question in a way of "how can i avoid inlining my 'setOrGetMethod' encapsulated here as 'modify' function like bfavaretto suggests?  Cause inlining that logic into an anonymous method just to get at _private seems unnecessary.  I can think of a way... I'd have to wrap all my _private vars in an object and pass the object?

Comment: @mrjustinmooser Yes, that would work. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: Okay just wanted to confirm this is a standard approach to essentially passing by reference.  Obviously the modify() here is hardcoding the specific property to set, so in reality I have a 'keyName' passed in so i do _private[keyName] so I can indeed change any private I wish.